# No type or protocol named 'ReformerProtocol' in .h, but .m works fine

Tags: ios, swift

I have a protocol in swift:

```
import Foundation

@objc protocol ReformerProtocol {
    func reformDataWithManager(apiManager: FSAPIClient) -> NSDictionary
}
```

In my Objective C .m if i define a method like:

```
- (NSDictionary *)fetchDataWithReformer:(id<ReformerProtocol>)reformer {
}
```

it works fine, but if i declare this method in .h file:

```
- (NSDictionary *)fetchDataWithReformer:(id<ReformerProtocol>)reformer;
```

The error is:

```
No type or protocol named 'ReformerProtocol'
```

Not sure the reason.

Comment: Have you imported the `-Swift` header?

Comment: yes, i think that's why in .m file it works.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You should simply forward-declare the protocol in the .h file before using it.

```
@protocol ReformerProtocol;
```

Comment: Thanks, it's a shame, i tried ```@class```. Not sure why it works fine in .m file

Comment: Because you imported the header.

Comment: I add this into .pch file: #import "Probject-Swift.h" this won't let .h file knows protocol exist?